# How do I append to a field in an existing column PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, append

Sorry about the title of the question, I don't quite know how to ask what I am trying to accomplish here. 
Perhaps my code samples below can be more of help to you. But first here is a little information.

I am using the PDO driver to execute queries to my database.

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE `support` SET `message` = `message` + :message WHERE `id` = :id AND `userid` = :uid");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':uid', $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':message', $smessage, PDO::PARAM_STR);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    $this->formatted_message($userid);
}
```

Comment: PHP concatenation is a dot, not a plus sign. This as an "FYI". But you're not doing it right; you need a special function for this.

Comment: No you are mistaken. I am trying to append to a field in my column. Not concatenate anything to a PHP variable.

Answer (score 3):

The plus sign is only for numbers in sql.

Mysql offers the function `concat` instead.

Your query would become:

```
UPDATE `support` SET `message` = concat(`message`, :message) WHERE `id` = :id AND `userid` = :uid
```

Comment: Thank you that's all I was trying to accomplish. I'll look further into mysql considering how simple the solution was.

Comment: The [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/functions.html) breaks down all the functions available. It's worth at least skimming that so you know what tools you have at your disposal.

Comment: Thank you I'll definitely check that out.